# Best way to reset keys which expires in few minutes in python

Tags: python

I have to reset my key (something like session key) every two hours, which is going to expire after that. which is the best way to implement a reactivation feature in my code?

there is no method available for me to check whether my key is still valid other than checking the status by performing some actions which require valid keys.

I'm looking for some solution with which i can use it for flexible expiring time (which is passed as a parameter) for my key.

Comment: Why are we voting to close this ?

Comment: you are going to need to provide a lot more information in order to get a helpful answer

Comment: *This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form*

Comment: If you want your answer reopened, please provide more info, make it more concrete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In outline:

1. Create an object class to represent each key;
2. Have as an element of each instance of that object it's timed life;
3. have a call-back to call the instance at the appropriate time;
4. the object decides to die or re-up at the time-out

Here is a trivial example:

```
import threading, time, random

class Key(object):
    results={}
    def __init__(self,refresh,name):
        self.refresh=refresh
        self.name=name
        self.t0=time.time()
        self.t=threading.Timer(refresh,self.now_what)
        self.t.start()

    def now_what(self):
        s='{}: {:6.4f}'.format(self.name,time.time()-self.t0)
        Key.results.setdefault(self.refresh,[]).append(s)
        # do the thing you want at this time ref with the Key...

    def time_left(self):
        return max(self.t0+self.refresh-time.time(),0)

keys=[Key(random.randint(2,15),'Key {}'.format(i)) for i in range(1,1001)]
t=time.time()
while any(key.time_left() for key in keys):
    if time.time()-t > 1:
        kc=filter(lambda x: x, (key.time_left() for key in keys))
        if kc:
            tmpl='{} keys; max life: {:.2f}; average life: {:.2f}'
            print tmpl.format(len(kc),max(kc),sum(kc)/len(kc))
            t=time.time()

for k in sorted(Key.results):
    print '\nKeys with {} secs life:'.format(k)
    for e in Key.results[k]:
        print '\t{}'.format(e)
```

Prints:

```
1000 keys; max life: 13.98; average life: 7.38
933 keys; max life: 12.98; average life: 6.85
870 keys; max life: 11.97; average life: 6.29
796 keys; max life: 10.97; average life: 5.80
729 keys; max life: 9.97; average life: 5.26
666 keys; max life: 8.96; average life: 4.68
594 keys; max life: 7.96; average life: 4.16
504 keys; max life: 6.96; average life: 3.77
427 keys; max life: 5.96; average life: 3.32
367 keys; max life: 4.95; average life: 2.74
304 keys; max life: 3.95; average life: 2.16
215 keys; max life: 2.95; average life: 1.76
138 keys; max life: 1.95; average life: 1.32
84 keys; max life: 0.95; average life: 0.72

Keys with 2 secs life:
    Key 26: 2.0052
    Key 27: 2.0053
    Key 41: 2.0048
    ...
Keys with 3 secs life:
    Key 4: 3.0040
    Key 31: 3.0065
    Key 32: 3.0111
    ...
Keys with 4 secs life:
...
```

You can see that there is some variability in accuracy, but it is with 1/100 sec for most purposes.